# FileNotFound exception after fetch, even though file exists in VSCode

Tags: java, github, visual-studio-code

I'm currently using GitHub desktop to fetch changes, and then opening the project in VSCode.

For whatever reason, any new files that come with the fetch throw FileNotFound exceptions after compiling (even though I can see the files in the project folders). If I go into a file, make an edit and save it the issue goes away and the compiler sees the files again.

Is there a way to "Refresh" the project files after a fetch. I am assuming a file pointer isn't resolving in some backend code somewhere.

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: The file may be in the project folder but did it get deployed with the application? Where? What code did you use to open it with? Too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Palette and choose **Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace** then **reload window**.